# How to replace a column in R by a modified column, dependent on filtered values? (removing outliers in panel data)

Tags: r, tidyverse, outliers, panel-data

I have a panel dataset that goes like this

| year | id | treatment_year | time_to_treatment | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 2011 | -11 | 2 |
| 2002 | 1 | 2011 | -10 | 3 |
| 2004 | 2 | 2015 | -9 | 22 |

and so on and so forth. I am trying to deal with the outliers by 'Winsorize'. The end goal is to make a scatterplot with time_to_treatment on the X axis and outcome on the Y.

I would like to replace the outcomes for each time_to_treatment by its winsorized outcomes, i.e. replace all extreme values with the 5% and 95% quantile values.
So far what I have tried to do is this but it doesn't work.

```
for(i in range(dataset$time_to_treatment)){
    dplyr::filter(dataset, time_to_treatment == i)$outcome <-  DescTools::Winsorize(dplyr::filter(dataset,time_to_treatment==i)$outcome)
}
```

I get the error - *Error in filter(dataset, time_to_treatment == i) <- `*vtmp*` :
could not find function "filter<-"*

Would anyone able to give a better way?
Thanks.

---

my actual data
where: conflicts = outcome, commission = year of treatment, CD_mun = id.

The concerned time period indicator is time_to_t

Groups:   year, CD_MUN, type [6]

| type | CD_MUN | year | time_to_t | conflicts | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr | dbl | dbl | dbl | int | dbl |
| manif | 1100023 | 2000 | -11 | 1 | 2011 |
| manif | 1100189 | 2000 | -3 | 2 | 2003 |
| manif | 1100205 | 2000 | -9 | 5 | 2009 |
| manif | 1500602 | 2000 | -4 | 1 | 2004 |
| manif | 3111002 | 2000 | -11 | 2 | 2011 |
| manif | 3147006 | 2000 | -10 | 1 | 2010 |

Comment: Question is, do you need the `for` loop at all? Have you tried without it?

Comment: What about `dplyr::mutate(dat, outcome_w=DescTools::Winsorize(outcome))`?

Comment: Thanks I tried making a function but dont see how I could add it back to my original dataset. @ChrisRuehlemann

Comment: thanks but I dont want to winsorize the entire outcome column, since values change over time. I want to do it for each individual time periods. @jay.sf

Comment: @suyash_n Maybe you could provide more suitable data with those time periods you mention. Please read [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038).

Comment: @jay.sf just updated the question with my actual data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start you may use this:

```
# The data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  time_to_treatment = seq(-15, 0, 1),
  outcome = sample(1:30, 16, replace=T)
)

# A solution without Winsorize based solely on dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(outcome05 = quantile(outcome, probs = 0.05), # 5% quantile
         outcome95 = quantile(outcome, probs = 0.95), # 95% quantile
         outcome = ifelse(outcome <= outcome05, outcome05, outcome), # replace
         outcome = ifelse(outcome >= outcome95, outcome95, outcome)) %>% 
  select(-c(outcome05, outcome95))
```

You may adapt this to your exact problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried adapting the code as follows. here conflicts = outcome in my data
`for(i in range(noliers$time_to_t)){
    filter(noliers, time_to_t == i)%>%
  mutate(outcome05 = quantile(conflicts, probs = 0.05), # 5% quantile
         outcome95 = quantile(conflicts, probs = 0.95), # 95% quantile
         outcome = ifelse(conflicts <= outcome05, outcome05, conflicts), # replace
         outcome = ifelse(conflicts >= outcome95, outcome95, conflicts)) %>% 
  select(-c(outcome05, outcome95))
}`.
however, nothing changes, even if i try with very narrow quantile ranges. :-/

Comment: Alright. Have you tried ```noliers %>% group_by(time_to_t) %>% ...``` instead of using a loop with a filter?

Comment: Well that didn't work either, totally at a loss

Comment: Okay. How many observations do you have per ```time_to_t```? More than one or two, I guess?

Comment: ... and if you want to use ```filter```. You should use ```dplyr::filter```, as there might be conflicts with other packages.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, "time periods" refer to `'commission'` column, you may use `ave`.

```
transform(dat, conflicts_w=ave(conflicts, commission, FUN=DescTools::Winsorize))
#    type  CD_MUN year time_to_t conflicts commission conflicts_w
# 1 manif 1100023 2000       -11         1       2011        1.05
# 2 manif 1100189 2000        -3         2       2003        2.00
# 3 manif 1100205 2000        -9         5       2009        5.00
# 4 manif 1500602 2000        -4         1       2004        1.00
# 5 manif 3111002 2000       -11         2       2011        1.95
# 6 manif 3147006 2000       -10         1       2010        1.00
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(type = c("manif", "manif", "manif", "manif", "manif", 
"manif"), CD_MUN = c(1100023L, 1100189L, 1100205L, 1500602L, 
3111002L, 3147006L), year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L), time_to_t = c(-11L, -3L, -9L, -4L, -11L, -10L), conflicts = c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L), commission = c(2011L, 2003L, 2009L, 2004L, 
2011L, 2010L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```